# 'Android' command is depreciated, cordova , Ionic2

Tags: cordova, ionic2

I am creating a Ionic2 + cordova project.

My Ionic info is

```
global packages:

@ionic/cli-utils : 1.2.0
Cordova CLI      : 7.0.1 
Ionic CLI        : 3.2.0
```

local packages:

```
@ionic/app-scripts              : 1.3.0
@ionic/cli-plugin-cordova       : 1.2.0
@ionic/cli-plugin-ionic-angular : 1.2.0
Cordova Platforms               : android 6.2.3
Ionic Framework                 : ionic-angular 3.0.1
```

System:

```
Node       : v6.10.3
OS         : Linux 4.4
Xcode      : not installed
ios-deploy : not installed
ios-sim    : not installed
```

This gives me error

```
Installing "cordova-plugin-network-information" for android
    Failed to install 'cordova-plugin-network-information': CordovaError: Failed to find 'ANDROID_HOME' environment variable. Try setting setting it manually.
    Failed to find 'android' command in your 'PATH'. Try update your 'PATH' to include path to valid SDK directory.
```

**echo $ANDROID_HOME** gives me

```
/home/raju/Android/Sdk
```

**android** gives me

```
The "android" command is deprecated.
For manual SDK, AVD, and project management, please use Android Studio.
For command-line tools, use tools/bin/sdkmanager and tools/bin/avdmanager
*************************************************************************
Invalid or unsupported command ""

Supported commands are:
android list target
android list avd
android list device
android create avd
android move avd
android delete avd
android list sdk
android update sdk
```

My **.profile** file has`# set PATH so it includes user's private bin directories
PATH="$HOME/bin:$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH"
export ANDROID_HOME="/home/raju/Android/Sdk/"
export PATH="${PATH}:${ANDROID_HOME}tools/:${ANDROID_HOME}platform-tools/"`

This problem occurs in new ionic2 cli.

Please help.

**EDIT**: cordova requirements gives`Requirements check results for android:
Java JDK: installed 1.8.0
Android SDK: installed true
Android target: installed android-25,android-24,android-23
Gradle: installed /usr/lib/gradle/3.5/bin/gradle`

Comment: what is the output of `cordova requirements`?

Comment: @suraj, please see EDIT

Comment: I cant see any issue.. maybe try reinstalling cordova-android platform?

Comment: Have you found any solution for it yet? I'm also facing this issue.